# Windows Update Error 0x800f0805

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-10-v21h2, 0x800f0805

I am using Windows 10 version 21H2 and Windows Updates have been failing for a while. I have tried every 'solution' I can find but nothing has worked so far.

Three updates are failing:

- Feature Update to Windows 10, version 22H2 - Failing with unknown error.
- 2023-10 Update for Windows 10, version 21H2 for x64-based systems (KB4023057) - Failing download with error 0x800f0805
- 2023-05 Update for Windows 10, version 21H2 for x64-based systems (KB5001716) - Failing download with error 0x80070643

I have searched the Microsoft Update Catalogue but cannot find any of these updates there, either by name or KB number, so am unable to install them manually.

I have tried stopping and starting the Update services, renaming the directories, etc., none of which have worked.

Short of a fresh install, which is out of the question until I have exhausted all avenues, I'm currently out of ideas so am hoping some secret genius here can help.

Comment: Post the Windows Update log. KB4023057 failing means you have not installed an update since March 2021. I have KB4023057 on the [Windows Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/search.aspx?q=kb4023057) but the update was never released for 21H2. Windows 10 21H2 stop receiving updates more than a year ago.

Comment: That is correct, I cannot install any updates. The Windows Update log does not go back that far, and the only recent entries just say that updates have failed to download.

Comment: I can’t help without the log.

Comment: Log Name:      Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient/Operational
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient
Date:          23/01/2024 11:22:44
Event ID:      31
Task Category: Windows Update Agent
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Failure,Download
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      XXXXX
Description:
Windows Update failed to download an update.

Comment: There is more to that log then that and that’s unreadable as a comment.

Comment: a) I cannot paste the whole thing, not enough characters in the comments box.
b) I can read it?
c) Sorted now anyway.

Comment: So don't use a comment box.

Comment: And place it where? Aside from the "Answer your question" option, I can only see the comments box where I may post. Care to offer some helpful advice?

Comment: The question body can be edited. It appears you have already solved your problem.  So, only go to the effort if you feel the information will be helpful to identify the problem and the resolution for other users.

Comment: @RichM Editing your question to add info to it is the norm here. Comments are not really for you, the asker, to add more info, they are for others to ask you for more info, and then you edit your main question to make it better. Editing is strongly encouraged and there is no downside to editing your question. Make your question the best it can be using the EDIT button and our questions down here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an older version of Windows 10.

At this point, you need to try a Windows 10 Repair Install

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally
> answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

This will bring Windows 10 up to the current version.

If the Repair Install with the Keep Everything Option fails to work, then back up and reinstall Windows 10 is the best next step.